# How to easily enable and disable Java in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator

My wife needs to have Java enabled to enter her timecard into ADP (grrrr), but can never remember how to do it using the Preferences pane. Is there a script I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found two scripts that when merged let me create two Automator services for her: [the core applescript](https://superuser.com/questions/540863/how-do-i-toggle-java-on-off-in-safari-browser) and then how to detect [if the checkbox is already on or off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9690129/1633251)

```
on run {input, parameters} -- use for both Automator services except for false/true below
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            click menu item "Preferences…" of menu "Safari" of menu bar item "Safari" of menu bar 1
            click button "Security" of tool bar 1 of window 1

            set theCheckbox to checkbox "Enable Java" of group 1 of group 1 of window "Security"
            tell theCheckbox
                set checkboxStatus to value of theCheckbox as boolean
                if checkboxStatus is false then click theCheckbox
                -- false for the 'Enable' script, true for the 'Disable' one
            end tell
            click button 1 of window "Security"
        end tell
    end tell
    return input
end run
```