# OSX tick menu bar checkbox

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify

[image: Screenshot]

For my application [MuteSpotifyAds](https://github.com/simonmeusel/MuteSpotifyAds/issues/2) I wan't to add a feature that automatically enables the Private Session mode.

To do so, I wan't to toggle the menu bar item `Private Session` in the menu `Spotify` of the OSX menu bar. I use the following applescript, which works:

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16497564/6286431

`tell application "System Events" to tell process "Spotify"
    tell menu bar item 2 of menu bar 0
        click
        click menu item "Private Session" of menu 1
    end tell
end tell`

The problem is that I have to check if the checkbox is already ticked, because else I would disable the `Private Session`.

**Is there a way to check if the menu checkbox is already ticked?**

I've already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9691068/6286431), but seems to only work for checkboxes in actual windows.

If you have a solution that does not use applescript, that's also good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information if the menu item is checked is in the attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" of the menu item

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Spotify"
    tell menu bar item 2 of menu bar 1 -- AppleScript indexes are 1-based
        tell menu item "Private Session" of menu 1
            set isChecked to value of attribute "AXMenuItemMarkChar" is "✓"
            if not isChecked then click it
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Works perfectly!